# Is it not possible to use an SOQL query, from an outside system like a mobile app, to fetch Knowledge articles?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud, knowledge-management

I understand that there are no article types once Knowledge is enabled on Lightining. Which means that the following query fails:

```
SELECT Article_Body__c,Id,KnowledgeArticleId,Question__c,Summary,Title FROM FAQ__kav
```

where FAQ was one of the article type (which is now a record type in lightning).

So, what is the workaround to this now?
Can i not fetch the articles on the mobile app using an SOQL query anymore?
Is REST Apis the only option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out to be the following:

```
SELECT Article_Body__c,Id,KnowledgeArticleId,Question__c,Summary,Title FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE RecordType.Name = 'FAQ'
```